# angularjs custom messages and logging

Tags: angularjs, sql-server, logging, angularjs-scope

What is the best way to store and access custom messages in Angularjs ?.
Example:

```
$scope.alert.msg = "Delete successful !!";

$scope.alert.msg = "Error deleting record.";
```

Instead of hard coding the custom messages , I would like to store in a single file ALL types of messages and access it by a KEY value.Any recommendation ?

Also how can I set up a logger for Angularjs so that all logs happen at one place.
This what I have done.

Instead of `$log.debug('Data saved!')`

I created a service as logService with methods like below

```
logData.logInfo = function(logMessage) {
    // information log me
    if (config.logLevel == 10) {
        $log.debug(logMessage);
        //TODO save logMessage to database
    }
}
logData.logError = function(logMessage) {
    if (config.emailError) {
        // log and email the error
        $log.debug(logMessage);
        //TODO Email
        //TODO save logMessage to database
    } else {
        // log only
        //TODO save logMessage to database
        $log.debug(logMessage);
    }
}
```

I then inject the logService to controllers and log the messages like below

`logService.logError(error.error_description);`

I am sure there can be better ways of logging. Any help is greatly appreciated ?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a factory to centralize your alerts.

```
.factory('Alerts', function() {
    return {
        "success": {
            "delete": "Delete succesful"
        },
        "error": {
            "delete": "Delete unsuccesful"
        }
    };
})
```

You can simply use you're alerts as in a component `Alerts.success.delete`.

As for the logging of the messages, you can turn the `$log.debug` on and off based on a variable in the config of the application.

```
.config(function($logProvider){
  $logProvider.debugEnabled(false);
})
```

You can add a global variable with a logging level and based on that level decide if you email or write to a database. I added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y4jrz4wL/7/) where I demonstrate how I would implement a logger. Don't forget to open your console to view the results.

I will also paste the content of the jsfiddle just incase.

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
    .constant('LOG_LEVEL', 1)
    .config(function($logProvider){
      $logProvider.debugEnabled(true);
    })
    .factory('Alerts', function() {
        return {
            "success": {
                "delete": "Delete succesful"
            },
            "error": {
                "delete": "Delete unsuccesful"
            }
        };
    })
    .factory('LogService', function($log, LOG_LEVEL) {
            function writeToDB () {
            //Write to db
        };
        function email () {
            //Email someone
        }
        return {
            error: function(msg) {
                $log.error(msg);
                if (LOG_LEVEL > 0) writeToDB(msg);
                if (LOG_LEVEL > 1) email(msg);
            },
            success: function(msg) {
                $log.log(msg);
            },
            debug: function (msg) {
                    $log.debug(msg);
            }
        }
    })
    .run(function(LogService, Alerts) {
        LogService.error(Alerts.error.delete);
        LogService.success(Alerts.success.delete);
        LogService.debug("Turn me on and off in the config!")
    })
```

Comment: looks great. what changes I need to make to  .factory('Alerts'  .... to get data as Alert.success.saved and Alert.error.saved ?

Comment: return {
        "success": {
            "delete": "Delete succesful"
        },
        "error": {
            "delete": "Delete unsuccesful"
        },
        "success": {
            "saved": "Message Saved successfully"
        },
        "error": {
            "saved": "Error saving data"
        }
    };

Comment: is this the correct way ?. Sorry I am new to angularjs

Comment: No problem! If you want to add a new alert to success you would change it to:
    "success": {
        "delete": "Delete succesful",
        "saved": "Save successful"
    },
The same goes for the error object. 
This is called an nested object. Alerts returns a object (indicated by the {} brackets) and "success" is a property from the alert object. Success is also an object which has the properties "delete" and "saved". [Read more about objects and properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Creating_new_objects)

Answer (score 0):

For handling messages in one place, I use `ngLocalize`. Here is the [link](http://doshprompt.github.io/angular-localization/) with the details.

In short,

You create a `/res/en-US/messages.lang.json` file in your app directory (or use any other localization you want). The file should have the following format:

```
{
  "msgError":"Error occurred",
  "msgUserLoggedIn":"Successfully logged in"
}
```

Next, include `ngLocalize` in the module where you want to use it. After that, you can use it in HTML as:

```
<div>
  {{ 'messages.msgUserLoggedIn' | i18n }}
</div>
```

or in your controller code as:

`var errorMessage = $filter('i18n')('messages.msgError');`